# how to remove duplicates from the get web service using angular js?

Tags: angularjs

```
$http.get(url).success(function(response) {
                $scope.adv = response.dataclt;
}
```

Data Structure:

```
{
    "promotions": [{
            "promoDisplayNbr": 6055,
            "promoName": "1001SS*1/4 HNY 5-2 TSTAT SIDE STACK",
            "promoBeginDate": 1128139200000,
            "promoEndDate": 1133326800000,
            "merchGroupCode": 30,
            "merchGroupNbr": 173,
            "prgCertNbr": 1584,
            "plgDbKey": null,
            "plgName": null,
            "promotionDisplayType": {
                "promotionDisplayTypeCd": 35,
                "promotionDisplayTypeDesc": "‌​SideStack"
            }]
    }
}
```

`$scope.adv` got the data collection.

I want to remove the duplicate elements and populate that list to dropdown using `ng-repeat`.

Comment: what data it contain ?

Comment: what defines a duplicate? We have no idea what your data structure is

Comment: Data Strucuture of single object is like this:{"promotions":
[{"promoDisplayNbr":6055,"promoName":"1001SS*1/4 HNY 5-2 TSTAT SIDE STACK",
"promoBeginDate":1128139200000,
"promoEndDate":1133326800000,
"merchGroupCode":30,
"merchGroupNbr":173,
"prgCertNbr":1584,
"plgDbKey":null,
"plgName":null,
"promotionDisplayType":{"promotionDisplayTypeCd":35,"promotionDisplayTypeDesc":"SideStack"},

Comment: update code format and add data structure

Comment: I have done using some logic like this.for(var i=0;i<response.proons.length;i++)
           {
           var despid=response.proons[i].pre.proyTypeDesc;
           if(!contains(ele,despid))
            {
            ele.push(despid);
            $scope.promobj.push(response.promotions[i].promotionDisplayType);
            }
           }
          function contains(a, obj) {
              for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                  if (a[i] === obj) {
                      return true;
                  }
              }
              return false;
          }